# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endStream'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a subplot of multiple images for each cluster I have a pdf with multiple pages, one for each cluster.

I am getting the following error:

```
File "sparsity_diagnosis.py", line 382, in <module>
    pdf.savefig(fig)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2473, in savefig
    figure.savefig(self, format='pdf', **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1565, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2232, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2540, in print_pdf
    file.endStream()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endStream'
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle
import h5py
import pdb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
import random

matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("cow.pdf")
with open('cow pickle', "rb") as f:
    cluster, example =pickle.load(f)
    for i in range(64):
        patches = example[str(i)]
        samp_size_100 = 100 if len(patches) >= 100 else len(patches)
        my_randoms_100 = random.sample(xrange(samp_size_100), 10)
        samp_size_500 = 500 if len(patches) >= 500 else len(patches) 
        my_randoms_500 = random.sample(xrange(samp_size_500), 10) 
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.set_canvas(plt.gcf().canvas)
        plt.axis('off')
        for idx in range(30):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 10, idx+1)
            if idx <10:
                img =  patches[idx]
            elif idx < 20:
                img =  patches[my_randoms_100[idx-10]]  
            else:
                img =  patches[my_randoms_500[idx-20]]
            img = np.transpose(img, (2,1,0))
            ax.imshow(img)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
    pdf.close()
```

any clue?

Comment: I edited my post with full traceback

Comment: Thanks; this is well outside my areas of expertise, but at least now someone that does know more about matplotlib can probably track what is going on here.

Comment: Have you looked at this example? http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html

Comment: it was working before, i made a change and it stopped working so i did version ciontrol and it started working again :)